# Integral over set of measure zero confusion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> I want to show that $\int_{\Delta}n|x|^nf(x)dA=\int_0^{2\pi}f(cos(\theta),sin(\theta))d\theta$, where $\Delta\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is the closed unit ball.

I've confused myself because I can write $\int_{\Delta}n|x|^nf(x)dA$ as $\int_{B_1(0)}n|x|^nf(x)dA+\int_{\partial\Delta}nf(x)dA$, where $B_1(0)$ is the open unit ball. Since the boundary $\partial\Delta$ has measure zero, we can disregard the second integral. But then $\int_{B_1(0)}n|x|^nf(x)dA$ should tend to zero as $n\to\infty$ because $n|x|^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for any $|x|<1$, and so I'm getting $0$ instead of $\int_0^{2\pi}f(cos(\theta),sin(\theta))d\theta$. Can someone explain the error?

Comment: "n $\int_{B_1(0)}n|x|^nf(x)dA$ should tend to zero as $n\to\infty$" What is your reasoning for that claim?

Comment: You need to justify bringing the limit under the integral to assume that $\int_\Delta n |x|^n f(x)\, dA \to 0$. For instance, you cannot use the Bounded Convergence Theorem here since $n |x|^n f(x)$ is not necessarily bounded on $\Delta$.

Comment: My thought was switching to polar coordinates. $\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}nr^{n+1}f(r,\theta)d\theta dr$. For any $r_0<1$, if we integrate over the circle of radius $r_0$, we have that $\int_0^{2\pi}nr_0^{n+1}f(r,\theta)d\theta\leq\int_0^{2\pi}nr_0^{n+1}Bd\theta=2\pi B nr^{n+1}$, where $B$ is a uniform bound for $f$ over the circle of radius $r_0$. Since $r_0<1$, this expression goes to zero as $n\to\infty$

Comment: That argument fails in the same way I was describing. You show that $\int_0^{2\pi} n r^{n+1} f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)\, d\theta \to 0$ for any $r\in(0,1)$ (pointwise convergence), but this is not enough in itself to conclude the integral $\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} n r^{n+1} f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)\, d\theta d r$ goes to $0$.

Comment: @TrevorNorton I see now what you mean

Comment: The difficulty is that $n|x|^n$ does not go to $0$ uniformly on the open unit ball, and that $f(x)$ may fail to be bounded on any open set  $U$ such that $U\supset \partial \Delta.$

Answer (score 1):

The result is a consequence of the following

**Lemma.** Let $f\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ be Riemann integrable and continuous at $1$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\int_0^1t^n\,f(t)\,dt=f(1).
$$

Proof. Since $f$ is Rieman integrable, it is bounded; let $B$ be a bound. Choose a sequence $a_n$ such that $0<a_n<1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^n=0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $1$ and $a_n\to1$, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that
$$
n\ge N\implies |f(t)-f(1)|\le\epsilon,\quad a_n\le t\le1.
$$
Then, for all $n\ge N$
\begin{align}
\Bigl|\,(n+1)\int_0^1t^n\,f(t)\,dt-f(1)\Bigr|&\le(n+1)\int_0^1t^n\,|f(t)-f(1)|\,dt\\
&=(n+1)\int_0^{a_n}t^n\,|f(t)-f(1)|\,dt+(n+1)\int_{a_n}^1t^n\,|f(t)-f(1)|\,dt\\
&\le2\,B\,a_n^{n+1}+\epsilon.
\end{align}
Since $a_n^{n+1}\to0$, the claim follows.